Prove that $p(2n) \geq p(n) + p(n-1) + \dots + p(1)$
This is a question from my combinatorics exam:

For a natural number $n$, prove that $p(2n) \geq p(n) + p(n-1) + \dots + p(1)$, where $p(m)$ is the number of number partitions of $m \in \mathbb N$.

I tried to prove this by induction but I got stuck, here is my attempt:

Let $n=1$ then we have $p(2) = 2 \geq 1 = p(1)$
Assume $p(2n) \geq p(n) + p(n-1) + \dots + p(1)$ is true for abitrary $n=m \in \mathbb N$. Note that this means $$\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m} p(2m, k)}_{=p(2m)} =  \color{red}{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m} p(2m-1, k-1)}+\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2m}p(2m-k, k)} \geq \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{k=1}^{i}\limits p(i, k)}_{=p(m) + \dots + p(1)}$$ where in the first equality I use the known recurrence relation for $p(m)$ and $p(m, k)$ denotes the number of $k$-partitions of number $m$.
Let's prove that 2. implies that the statement holds for $n=m+1$ as well. Consider the following $$p(2(m+1)) =\color{\red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2(m+1)} p(2m+1, k-1)} + \color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2(m+1)} p(2(m+1)-k, k)}$$ where we used the recurrence relation again.
Here my idea is to show that these red and blue sums are greater or equal than the red and blue sums above, respectively. We can take out 2 sum members from these latter sums and have all the sums have matching upper bounds of $2m$, then I essentially need to show that $$\begin{align} p(2m+1, k-1) &\geq p(2m-1, k-1)\\ p(2m-k, k)&\geq p(2(m+1)-k, k) \end{align}$$ which further boils down to showing that $p(a, j) \geq p(a-1, j)$ is true in general for any $a, j$, which seems fairly obvious by common sense and given that the number of $k$-partitions is non-decreasing for any number. But I'm stuck on how to show this rigorously. If I had this the rest of the proof seems straightforward, assuming the rest of it is correct. How to proceed here, is the general idea of the solution alright? Feel free to post a better one if you know of it. thanks


For the original problem: if you partition $2n$, there are two possibilities: the largest number smaller than $n$ and the largest number greater or equal to  $n$. Then for the latter, if the largest number is $n+i$, the number of partition in such group is $p(n-i)$
